# Transform inserted and deleted tables into an audit table?

Tags: sql-server

Based on the following [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4ed10), I need to audit the changes in the table.

The trigger should insert 2 records in the audit table and the ´changes´ column should look like this:

```
id||1^name||Mr.^
```

for the first insert, and:

```
id||1^name||Mrs.^
```

for the second insert.

The SQL statement should be dynamic and it should loop through the `inserted` and/or `deleted` tables, and for each row found, loop through the columns and build a string that will be written back in the `changes` column of the audit table.

Is it possible to achieve this in the trigger? And is it possible to keep the trigger generic so does one need to know the column names explicitly?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: (1) there is no such thing as ONE generic trigger which observes all tables. every table would need its own trigger. (2) you should do as little as possible within a trigger. it fires once per statement and your user/procs/whatever will have to wait for it to finish

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to have different triggers for update, insert and delete.
try these statement for each of them:

```
-- for insert
INSERT INTO audit(
  item_table, 
  changes) 
SELECT
  'titles',
  [id] + '|^NULL|' + inserted.[name] + '^'

-- for update
INSERT INTO audit(
  item_table, 
  changes) 
SELECT
  'titles',
  [id] + '|^' + deleted.[name] + '|' + inserted.[name] + '^'


-- for delete
INSERT INTO audit(
  item_table, 
  changes) 
SELECT
  'titles',
  [id] + '|^' + deleted.[name] + '|NULL^'
```